# fontlist.info for smart tv not work

Tags: samsung-smart-tv, smart-tv

who can help me? can somebody send example of fontlist.info for smart tv .
my fontlist.info

```
Font List
robotocondensed1 : robotocondensed1.ttf : default
```

my css

```
#serials {font-family: robotocondensed1;}
```

font not available

but if i use

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'roboto_condensed';
src: url('../font/robotocondensed-regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;}

#serials {font-family: roboto_condensed, "Helvetica CY", "Arial Narrow", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;}
```

font available

Answer (score 3):

fontlist.info only works for 2010 and 2011 devices (Maple)
And for 2012 devices and later is using @font-face (WebKit)

You can use both of them to make it works on all devices

Comment: 2010 and 2011  suppored @font-face  too or i need dev two ways?

Comment: No, it's not supported. I mean just put the fontlist.info and @ font-face both of it in your code. So the 2010/11 will search the fontlist.info and 2012 later will search the @font-face